# How to make SSIS For each loop move to next record on failure

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a for each loop in an SSIS package that loops through an object.  Within the loop there are multiple steps, each of which will include error handling.  The problem is on some of the steps with expression constraints for the next step, SSIS is finding a path forward despite erroring on the step.  What I would like is that when a step errors the loop finishes error handling without doing any further steps in the package and then moves to the next record.

How can I force it to do that?

Answer (score 0):

click on the step causing error . in the properties window change the ForceExecutionResult and ForecExecutionValue properties To Success.

Comment: If I force it to succeed won't it just continue past the step?  I want it to stop doing steps for that record and move to the next record (after doing error handling) Not do all of the steps for that record.

Comment: Add an error connector from the task that throw exception to the error handling tasks

Comment: I have two connectors, they're expression connectors, it is traveling down one.  Is there a way I can capture the state of the previous task and put an and in the expression that strictly requires a success from the previous step?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of the project.?

Comment: To create an error handling connector. Add a connector and double click on it. Change the constraint value from success to failure

Answer (score 0):

Apparently a constraint can also include an expression, I didn't see that before.